# Can I fire a Text Changed Event for an asp.net Text Box before it loses focus?

Tags: c#, asp.net, javascript

I have an asp.net TextBox in which I want to check if the text entered into the TextBox is `> 0`.  It works once I tab out or click out of the TextBox, but if I keep focus on the TextBox, it won't fire the Text Changed Event, so I have the following scenario, I want to enable something if and only if the `TextBox.Text.Length = 0`.  Now, if I put my caret in the TextBox and delete all the characters and then leave the caret in the TextBox so it still has focus and take my mouse and click a button,  it will not do what it was supposed to do because it never fired the Text Changed Event.  How would something like this be handled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

friend, `keyup`, `keydown` and `keypress` are your friends

Comment: Are these events for the TextBox?

Comment: Yes, in javascript, you can bind on these.  It is a little bit difficult in ASP.Net because you have to set the attributes in the code behind, but it is doable.

Answer (score 1):

The best idea is to write some client-side javascript to do what you want. The TextChanged event handler requires a postback to the server, and posting back to the server before a text box loses focus is impossible. Unless that is what you intend, I would suggest the former.

Answer (score 0):

you can also use the setInterval javascript method to check for a change in the value of the textbox on a timed basis.  just remember, you need to use the form name followed by control name and value to reference the control.

```
setInterval(MethodName, 100);

function MethodName()
{
   if(formname.controlid.value.length > 0)
   {
     //do something here
   {
}
```